# empty row when exporting dataframe with openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I try to export an existing DataFrame to an Excel file using openpyxl.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import Workbook

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for rows in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(rows)

wb.save(filename = 'test.xlsx')
```

When doing so, I always get an empty row in the output file after the header row.

I know I can delete the 2nd row manually, but is there no other way?

I have already tried this here - with the same result:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import Workbook

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

rows = dataframe_to_rows(df)

for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)

wb.save(filename = 'test.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 7):

Make `index=False`:

```
for rows in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(rows)
```

Comment: I think this should be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: ok if the index is not important, but it doesn't work if index is important to keep, like from pandas pivot for example

Answer (score 2):

You can set the index as a column and then use index=False

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import Workbook

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
rows = dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False)

for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)

wb.save(filename = 'test.xlsx')
```

The Output of the excel file will be

[image: Output in the excel file]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. However, I wanted to keep index=true.
So I just deleted the second row after the loop

```
for rows in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(rows)
ws.delete_rows(2)
```

This worked for me

Comment: That's not the answer the original poster was aiming for, see his question: "I know I can delete the 2nd row manually, but is there no other way?"

Comment: it technically deletes the second row automatically. I posted it, because the previous answer was not a sufficient solution if you want to keep the index.

Comment: but it also deletes the header name because index name is in second row?

Answer (score 0):

With [Openpyxl 3.0.7](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html?highlight=pandas#working-with-pandas-dataframes), you can directly use *dataframe_to_rows*
as a generator and pass dataframe with index reset like bellow so your dataframe is not changed:

```
def write_to_sheet(df, ws):

    for r in dataframe_to_rows(df.reset_index(level=0), index=False, header=True):
        ws.append(r)

    for cell in ws['A'] + ws[1]:
        cell.style = 'Pandas'
```